# How to change username in Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

Hello this is my first time using Stack.

I want to start by a basic question.
How do you change the username and profile picture?

Comment: Check: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25740/is-it-possible-to-change-your-username

Comment: Try to google your question before you ask it on any Stack Exchange. That way you can avoid being flagged as a duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

- Click on your name in the top right
- Click on the tab "Edit Profile & Settings"
- Edit "Display name" field
- Change picture